# Why is the user data not inserted into referral tables when a user signup via a referral link?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration, referrals

I am trying to build a login/registration system where all registered users will have a unique referral link for referring new user. And i also created a table to keep track of the total number of users a particular user has referred to the system.
everything works fine but the problem is that even though a visitor signup through a referral link the the referral table is never updated

CODE :

```
if(isset($ref)){
    echo $ref;
    //implement the code here
    $send_user_id = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');
    $send_user_id->bindValue(':user_name',$ref,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $send_user_id->execute();
    if($send_user_id->rowCount()){
        $send_user_id->fetchobject();
        $rsid = $send_user_id->user_id;
        //insert into referral
        $referral = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO referrals (sending_user_id,new_user_id,new_user_status) VALUES (:sending_user_id, :new_user_id, 0)');
        $referral->bindValue(':sending_user_id',$rsid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $referral->bindValue('new_user_id',$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $referral->execute();
    }else{
        $this->errors[] = "invalid referral id";
    }
    $this->registration_successful = true;
}
```

CONSTRUCTOR :

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
    $ref = trim($_GET['ref']);
    if(isset($ref)){
        echo $ref;
    }else{
        echo "ref was not define";
    }
} else {
    $ref = false;
}
// if we have such a POST request, call the registerNewUser() method
if (isset($_POST["btn-save"])) {
    echo $ref;
    $this->registerNewUser($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password_new'], $_POST['user_password_repeat'], $_POST["captcha"], $ref);
```

thanks!

Comment: A more specific question title would help - at the moment it sounds as if you want someone to do everything for you, which isn't actually the case.

Comment: not really! i just need someone to find the bug i can't see

Comment: so edit the title.

Comment: OK! Do you have  better suggestion for the title??

Comment: "Why are referral links not being inserted into MySQL?"

Comment: perfect! Thanks alot

Comment: You forgot a colon before `new_user_id` in your bindValue thing.

Comment: aww i see it now! let me try it. thanks @TomUdding

Comment: @TomUdding i have corrected that and it still not working

Comment: Enable PDO error reporting with this `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` (after you connect) and see if it returns an error.

Comment: ok! let me try it..